# What's the difference between "strategist" and " tactician"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What's the difference between "strategist" and " tactician"? As a Chinese ,I don't get the hidden meaning of it.

Any answer ?? Help me learn ...

[image]

Comment: Same as the famous difference between *strategy* (long term objectives and plan of action) and *tactics* (short term methods of overcoming obstacles in pursuit of the longer-term strategy).

Comment: A CEO of a company or a president of a country should be a strategist, not a tactician.

Comment: what has your dictionary revealed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way I have of differentiating the two is that a Strategist will have a plan that has long-reaching connotations. A Tactician is more focussed on the situation on a smaller scale.

This might not be the best example but its the only way I know to explain it:

A Strategist has a map of the county/region and makes plans on a large scale. Keeping an eye on the overall goal (Take the region, destroy headquarters)

"Send the troops through this town, while this platoon comes in from the coast, then air support will have a clear run to point x"

The Tactician has a map that covers one town, and makes plans based on the local area, keeping an eye on the smaller objectives required to take the town.

"If Alpha climb this ladder to the roof, they can cover Bravo as they flank around the church to take out the AA guns. If Charlie places charges on the bridge it will cut off the enemy escape. Delta then take the mansion and the town is ours"

Sorry if it sounds a little convoluted but its how I differentiate the two.